# Temporarily Override Function JS

Tags: javascript

I am trying to override some functions temporarily.

I have this on my main function.js

```
var getFilters = function() {
    return "";
}
```

I load some pages with AJAX, so when it load I want a different return, and I can do it, like this

```
getFilters = function() {
    return "different filters";
}
```

The problem comes when I load another page with AJAX, and doesn't have getFilters function. and everything brakes

Error:

```
TypeError: Can only call HTMLCollection.item on instances of HTMLCollection
```

Any ideas?

The error it's because when I load a new page with AJAX, I call getFilters but the function doesn't exist because File B (loaded with AJAX), I remove it.

```
function loadPage (page, type) {
    loaded = page;
    data = type;
    filters = getFilters();
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You need to show the rest of your code.

Comment: The error seems pretty unrelated to the code you posted.

Comment: @FelixKling Sorry I just edit my question explaining the error

Comment: I still don't see where the error should be thrown. You are not calling `.item()` anywhere.

Comment: This whole concept of setting a global before you call a function is generally a bad practice.  You should pass a `getFilters()` function to `loadPage` and then in `loadPage` check to see if the argument is a valid function before trying to call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something you can do is like.

```
//Saving the original func

var org_foo = window.foo;

//Assigning proxy fucnc

window.foo = function(args){

   //Performing checks

   if(checkCondition(args)){

     //Calling original funcs

     org_foo(args);
   }
};
```